# How to override equal in python?

Tags: python, pytest

I need `transaction` and `other_transaction` to be equal. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

```
    def test_eq_LedgerTransaction():
>       assert LedgerTransaction.__eq__(transaction, equal_transaction) is True          
E       assert False is True
E        +  where False = <function LedgerTransaction.__eq__ at 0x7f49c3183550>(transaction, equal_transaction)
E        +    where <function LedgerTransaction.__eq__ at 0x7f49c3183550> = LedgerTransaction.__eq__
```

Code

```
class LedgerTransaction():
    def __init__(self, date: str, payee: str, amount: float):
        self.date = date
        self.payee = payee
        self.amount = float(amount)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self == other

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Transaction:{self.date, self.payee, self.amount}'

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.date, self.payee, self.amount))


# Tests
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def transaction():
    return LedgerTransaction("2021/12/31", "transaction", 5.0)


@pytest.fixture
def equal_transaction():
    return LedgerTransaction("2021/12/31", "transaction", 5.0)


@pytest.fixture
def other_transaction():
    return LedgerTransaction("2021/12/31", "peach", 5.0)


def test_eq_LedgerTransaction():
    assert LedgerTransaction.__eq__(transaction, equal_transaction) is True
    assert LedgerTransaction.__eq__(transaction, other_transaction) is False
```

Comment: Overriding `__eq__` with, essentially, the default version of `__eq__` is unlikely to achieve anything useful anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare each field, so like the equal should be something like:

```
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.date == other.date and self.payee == other.payee and self.amount == other.amount
```

Right now you're just comparing the references to the objects, so like their addresses in memory rather than the actual contents of the objects.

Comment: Thank you. `return self.__hash__() == other.__hash__()` seems to work as well. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: It'll only be wrong if they ever hash into the same thing but are not equal, which is pretty unlikely, but something that's still possible. Like the contract between hash code and equals is that things that are equal need to have the same hash code, but things that are different could also potentially have the same hash.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate `LedgerTransaction` with [@dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) and let the interpreter generate the methods for you.